# Express router "res" object has to take me to other pages

Tags: node.js, express

See the example below:

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.post('/api/postAgree', function(req, res, next){
    userModel.findOneAndUpdate(
        {profileID: req.session.facebookProfileId},
        {$push:{postsAgreed: req.query.postID}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},

        function(err, model) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);   
            }
        }
    )
```

Now, the MongoDB operation is already done and I want to stay on the same page.

Will I be doing this:

```
res.render('theSamePageIamOn', {foo:bar});
```

I know this works but it seems like it is a very inefficient way of doing it.

So my question really is: If I have a button on a page which makes an API call but I want to stay on the same page, how will I do that? The res.(options) function sort of is made like it has to take me to other pages

Comment: I'm totally confused at what your question is...

Comment: You probably want to make an ajax call to the server instead of navigating

Comment: @GiladArtzi - I make the call on the HTML page and the handler (apiRouter) handles the traffic that comes in. I think making an AJAX call will defeat the purpose as the router object in Express is made specifically for that. It's just that I don't understand what I will have to do so it doesn't go to another page every time a button which makes an API call is is clicked

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Example:
Page I am on: /currentPage
Button I click: updateSomething

When I click the button, I want it to do it's thing and I want to be on the same page. Express' router object seems like it expects the user to go to another page each time an API call is handled

Comment: Actually if you have an endpoint on your server that its only purpose is to update your server/db, AJAX is exactly the way to go. Reloading the same page and have the DB updated as a side effect is rather inefficient.

Comment: Yes, you want to make it an AJAX call, and use `res.json()` to send back any data to the client.

Comment: @GiladArtzi & robertklep - thanks for the help. My next question was going to be how the front-end will update itself when the data is updated but I believe that will be front-end stuff, i.e.: AngularJS, which I can push aside for now as it will be picked up once my whole back-end is ready. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robertklep and @GiladArtzi - it should be an AJAX call and the response should be in the form of:

```
res.json()
```

Then the response can be handled by the frontend using other tools like: Angular

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're talking about, just call the function....

```
function doesSomething (args) {
    console.log(args)
}

apiRouter.post('/api/postAgree', function(req, res, next){
    doesSomething("HELLO")    
});
```

Function calls don't *expects the user to go to another page each time an API call is handled*.

Comment: Yes but when using express, the call will go on forever unless you send a response back (frontend won't know when the call has finished executing). See my accepted answer in case you are curious. Thanks for the input